# Difference between manylinux1 vs manylinux2020 wheel files in PIP Installer

Tags: python, pip, python-wheel, python-manylinux

I am facing a weird issue in Python, The Issue is `cryptography-2.9.2-cp35-abi3-manylinux2010_x86_64.whl` is not working on the SLES OS.

I have a CI/CD added to my repo and when I am downloading the packages from requirements.txt into local folder `dist-packages`. The Jenkins Slave machine runs on RedHat Linux. Hence it is downloading with this file `cryptography-2.9.2-cp35-abi3-manylinux2010_x86_64.whl` whereas my runtime is in SLES OS 11 this takes `cryptography-2.9.2-cp35-abi3-manylinux1_x86_64.whl`.

This particular dependency `cryptography-2.9.2-cp35-abi3-manylinux2010_x86_64.whl` is getting downloaded from RedHat and when I am re-distributing it to SLES OS, this dependency is failed with the below error.

```
 ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement cryptography>=2.1.4 (from azure-identity->-r requirements.txt (line 2)) (from versions: none)
    ERROR: No matching distribution found for cryptography>=2.1.4 (from azure-identity->-r requirements.txt (line 2))
```

If I change the dependency name from `cryptography-2.9.2-cp35-abi3-manylinux2010_x86_64.whl` to `cryptography-2.9.2-cp35-abi3-manylinux1_x86_64.whl` it is working fine on the SLES OS machines.

When I check in the PyPI https://pypi.org/project/cryptography/#modal-close (These two files are the same in size but has different hash value)

I would like to understand the differences between manylinux1_x86_64 vs manylinux2010_x86_64 in python packages.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0571/

Answer (score 8):

According this article: [manylinux tag](https://github.com/pypa/manylinux/blob/master/README.rst), manylinux2010 means it require `pip >= 19.0`

```sh
sudo python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

may help.

---

The goal of the manylinux project is to provide a convenient way to distribute binary Python extensions as wheels on Linux. This effort has produced [PEP 513](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0513/) which is further enhanced by [PEP 571](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0571/) defining `manylinux2010_x86_64` and `manylinux2010_i686` platform tags.

```
╔════════════════╦══════════════════════════════════╗
║  manylinux tag ║ Client-side pip version required ║
╠════════════════╬══════════════════════════════════╣
║  manylinux2014 ║ pip >= 19.3                      ║
║  manylinux2010 ║ pip >= 19.0                      ║
║  manylinux1    ║ pip >= 8.1.0                     ║
╚════════════════╩══════════════════════════════════╝
```

Comment: [PEP 600](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0600/) has superseded 513, 571, 599. The new scheme is `manylinux_${GLIBCMAJOR}_${GLIBCMINOR}_${ARCH}`. Example: `manylinux_2_17_x86_64`.